PWR meter 3 click board and ACS37800 issue

I am using power meter 3 click board. The DIO0 and DIO1 leds on click board are continuously ON even when connected to 3.3V. Is it expected? because the click boards documentation says if there are any anamolies in the board then these two LEDs glow. But I have connected the fresh box packed board. And I see with 3-4 boards.
To measure vrms and irms I am using the ACS37800 library code for input 230 VAC it gives 1.5 V vrms and 0.06A for 40W bulb which is wrong. Are there any configurations need to do before measuring the vrms and irms.

I am using PWR meter 3 click - 90A board. I s there a separate library for this board. The library I am using is SparkFun_ACS37800_Arduino_Library.h

Are you using the PWR Meter 3 Click - 30A or PWR Meter 3 Click - 90A board?

I am using PWR Meter 3 Click - 90A board
